# Sum Values of Rows for Duplicate DropDownList Selected Item inside a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a GridView inside my inventory application... I am using that grid view for product out... its is working fine but the thing i want is to check that if same product of same vendor is selected multiple times in gridview like i did in the picture then Sum its Quantity to ensure it is less than its Stock.
For single product it will just compare it with its Stock but For Every duplicate products, value of quantity will be added and compare it with its stock..
Any help would be highly appreciated...
[image]

e.g Computer Zone's Keyboard is selected twice and its has a stock of 15  ... I want to sum the quantity 10+7= 17 and throw a message if it is greater than its Stock which is 15 else save it as a row... 
and Computer Zone's Pen is selected twice (it can be thrice or more)and its has a stock of 50 ...  quantity 10+60= 70 and throw a message if it is greater than its Stock which is 50...

Answer (score 1):

You could use javascript or jQuery to calculate total quantity of same product, then compare it with available stock of this product. The followling sample used jQuery.

To do calculation, first you should assign name or class to all item in your grid. Sample row should look like this.

```
<tr>
    <td class="no">XX</td>
    <td><select  class="vendor" >... </select></td>
    <td><select  class="product" >...</select></td>
    <td><input class="stock" value="YY" readonly="true"></td>
    <td><input class="quantity" value="ZZ"></td>
</tr>
```

Then you add handler for change event of item *Quantity*

```
$('.quantity').change(function(e){
    var quantity = $(this);
    var row = quantity.closest("tr"); 
    var selectedVendor = $(".vendor option:selected", row).val();
    var selectedProduct = $(".product option:selected", row).val();

    // Get all row that have the same vendor and product 
    var sameRows = $(".product option:selected[value='" + selectedProduct + "']", $(".vendor option:selected[value='" + selectedVendor + "']").closest("tr")).closest("tr");

    // Calculate total quantity of same product
    var total = 0;
    sameRows.each(function() {
        total += parseInt($(".quantity", this).val());
    });

    // Compare total quantity and stock
    var stock = parseInt($(".stock", row).val()); 
    if (total > stock) {
        alert("Quantity access available stock");
        quantity.focus();
    }
});
```

You should also consider to add similar handler for dropdown *Vendor* and *Product*.

I've created a demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/e8x6bj9n/), you could check.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on RowDataBound of gridview easily.

Just you need to get the quantity,stock,product and vendor. however you can also do this by below function, it will give you records if there is something duplicate in gridview.

```
 public void HighlightDuplicate(GridView gridview)
{
    for(int currentRow = 0; currentRow < gridview.Rows.Count - 1; currentRow++)
    {
        GridViewRow rowToCompare = gridview.Rows[currentRow];
        for (int otherRow = currentRow + 1; otherRow < gridview.Rows.Count; otherRow++)
        {
            GridViewRow row = gridview.Rows[otherRow];
            bool duplicateRow = true;
            //example: check Duplicate on column vendor(cell#0) and product(cell#1)
            if ((rowToCompare.Cells[0].Text) != (row.Cells[0].Text) && (rowToCompare.Cells[1].Text) != (row.Cells[1].Text))
            {
                duplicateRow = false;
            }
            else if (duplicateRow)
            {
                rowToCompare.Cells[1].Text = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Text) + Convert.ToInt32(rowToCompare.Cells[1].Text);
row.Visible=false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this function you can check we are comparing the rows and inside we have cell and checking the cell values.

```
  if ((rowToCompare.Cells[0].Text) != (row.Cells[0].Text) && (rowToCompare.Cells[1].Text) != (row.Cells[1].Text))
        {
            duplicateRow = false;
        }
        else if (duplicateRow)
        {
            rowToCompare.Cells[1].Text = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Text) + Convert.ToInt32(rowToCompare.Cells[1].Text); 
row.Visible=false;
        }
```

In this part we compare the cell index 0 and 1, these should not be same if same means we have vendor and product same. if vendor and product are same then are combining their value and setting to one row only and second row i set visible false you can perform some other operation if you want and also here you can check after addition of both rows values if either quantity greater or less and you can do any operation accordingly.
you can call this function after DataBind(). for example if gridview id is Gridview1 then:

```
  HighlightDuplicate(this.GridView1);
```